# Setting Hadoop number of mapper with input split not working

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, mapper

I am trying to run a hadoop job multiple times with different number of mapper and reducer. I have set the configuration :

> - mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize
> - mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
> - mapreduce.job.maps

My filesize is 1160421275, when i tried to configure it with 4 mappers and 3 reducers in this code:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
long size = hdfs.getContentSummary(new Path("input/filea").getLength();
size+=hdfs.getContentSummary(new Path("input/fileb").getLength();
conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize", String.valueOf((size/4)));
conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize", String.valueOf((size/4)));
conf.set("mapreduce.job.maps",4);
....
job.setNumReduceTask(3);
```

The size/4 gives 290105318. The execution of the job gives the output below:

```
2016-11-19 12:30:36,426 INFO  [main] input.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(287)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2016-11-19 12:30:36,535 INFO  [main] input.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(287)) - Total input paths to process : 4
2016-11-19 12:30:36,572 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(396)) - number of splits:7
```

The number of splits is 7, not 4, and the Output of the success job is:

```
File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=18855390277
    FILE: Number of bytes written=14653469965
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=39184416
    Map output records=36751473
    Map output bytes=787022241
    Map output materialized bytes=860525313
    Input split bytes=1801
    Combine input records=0
    Combine output records=0
    Reduce input groups=25064998
    Reduce shuffle bytes=860525313
    Reduce input records=36751473
    Reduce output records=1953960
    Spilled Records=110254419
    Shuffled Maps =21
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=21
    GC time elapsed (ms)=1124
    CPU time spent (ms)=0
    Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
    Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=6126829568
Shuffle Errors
    BAD_ID=0
    CONNECTION=0
    IO_ERROR=0
    WRONG_LENGTH=0
    WRONG_MAP=0
    WRONG_REDUCE=0
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=0
File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=77643084
```

The map shows that it processed 21 shuffled maps. I want it to processed just 4 mappers. For the reducer it gives the correct number of files with the total number of 3. Are my mapper split size settings wrong?

Comment: AFAIK those confs are fine. How many files are there at input location ?

Comment: For file A there is 1 file, for file B there are 4 files.

Comment: When i use 9, it comes out with 10 splits

Comment: what is the InputFormatter you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using TextInputFormat.

1. If you have multiple files, then at least one mapper will be spawned for each file.  If file size (not cumulative but individual) is more than block size (which you have tweaked by setting min and max) again more mappers will be spawned.
2. Try using combineTextInputFormat, that will help you in acheiving what you want, but still may be not exactly 4.
3. Look at logic of InputFormats that you are using to determine, how many mappers will be spawned.